# Unable to mount USB on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: usb, mount, 15.10, gparted

I was trying to create a bootable Windows 7 USB stick using the instructions in the blog post below:

- [CREATE A BOOTABLE WINDOWS 7 USB DRIVE FROM LINUX (TESTED ON UBUNTU)](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html)

But after trying to format the `/dev/sdb` partition to **ntfs** from **GParted**, I'm unable to get the USB to show up. I pulled out and plugged the USB back in. Below is what shows up in GParted currently:

[image]

I tried using `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and then plugged in the USB. Below is the output:

```
Jan  2 23:09:58 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34946.380885] usb 3-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 29 using ehci-pci
Jan  2 23:09:58 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34946.487435] usb 3-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0718, idProduct=0619
Jan  2 23:09:58 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34946.487440] usb 3-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan  2 23:09:58 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34946.487443] usb 3-1.3: Product: Ridge
Jan  2 23:09:58 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34946.487445] usb 3-1.3: Manufacturer: Imation
Jan  2 23:09:58 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34946.487447] usb 3-1.3: SerialNumber: 0707426E0AAA6E83
Jan  2 23:09:58 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34946.487862] usb-storage 3-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jan  2 23:09:58 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34946.487962] scsi host19: usb-storage 3-1.3:1.0
Jan  2 23:09:58 chaudharyp-PC mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 29: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3"
Jan  2 23:09:58 chaudharyp-PC mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 29 was not an MTP device
Jan  2 23:09:59 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34947.486558] scsi 19:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Imation  Ridge            PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jan  2 23:09:59 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34947.487203] sd 19:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Jan  2 23:10:02 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34950.514732] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] 15261696 512-byte logical blocks: (7.81 GB/7.27 GiB)
Jan  2 23:10:02 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34950.517199] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Jan  2 23:10:02 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34950.517202] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
Jan  2 23:10:02 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34950.519059] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Jan  2 23:10:02 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34950.519061] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jan  2 23:10:02 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34950.580889]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
Jan  2 23:10:02 chaudharyp-PC kernel: [34950.588909] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I used `lsblk` and got the following output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   350M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   200G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   450M  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   520G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0  93.1G  0 part /
├─sda7   8:7    0  93.1G  0 part /home
└─sda8   8:8    0  24.5G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   7.3G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   200M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   1   7.1G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

`sdb` is visible here. It is also showing up in GParted. But it isn't showing up in the "Files" window.

I tried mounting `/dev/sdb1` using `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` and then ran `sudo mount` and got the following output:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

The USB is still not showing up in "Files".

Please help me for this.

Comment: Where is the USB not showing up?

Comment: Run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a terminal and plug the USB. Add the terminal output to your question.

Comment: `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`. You have to use the partition number.

Comment: @A.B. tried doing that. Still not showing up in "Files". Also, how do I know which one of `sdb1` and `sdb2` to mount?

Comment: @A.B. I tried `sudo mount` command to check the mounted devices. Pasted the output in question.

Comment: @chaudharyp did you use `sudo` when you did `mount /deb/sdb1 /mnt`?

Comment: @chaudharyp also, i think that `/dev/sdb1` is the NTFS windows bootloader, and that `/dev/sdb2` is the part that actually contains the data

Comment: @zwork Yes, I did use `sudo` while executing the command. And, according to GParted, `/dev/sdb1` is fat32, and `/dev/sdb2` is ntfs. Although, my USB is 8 GB, so `/dev/sdb2` is definitely the one containing data. I tried mounting `/dev/sdb2` on `/mnt` also but to no avail.

Comment: @chaudharyp have you tried just reformatting the drive in either GParted or in the stock Disks program?

Comment: So you know the legal implications of using a Windows 7 ISO, right?

Comment: @zwork It worked. I tried reformatting `/dev/sdb2` to fat from stock Disks tool and it worked. But I don't understand why ntfs didn't work and all this started when I formatted `/dev/sdb2` to ntfs from GParted.

Comment: @EduardoCola If I have the original product key, it shouldn't matter. Right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @chaudharyp there may have been something that went wrong w/ GParted when it formatted the disk, b/c NTFS should be read/writeable by default.

Comment: @EduardoCola if they have a valid license, it is legal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/sdb` is your USB drive, and GParted is showing it correctly. It should be mounting fine in Nautilus. The USB drive is also bootable.

With the information you gave us in your question, that's the best I can do.

EDIT: Reformat the disk, as we know that works :)

EDIT 2: You can use `unetbootin` to make a Windows Install USB that is bootable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this thread and if it doesn't work try something related to it, it surely will work out. Otherwise let me know https://superuser.com/questions/835477/how-to-format-read-only-pendrive

Comment: It is is considered good practice if you insert a summary into you answer instead of mentioning a link alone because the referenced page can disappear over time.

Comment: I am a new user. I'll remember from next time. Thanks